# Custom Data and Screens

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I have created a Custom Data field of the field type 
Alphanumeric Select
with 3 selectable options - I want to be able to edit the options that can be selected, but when I try I get an error

"This option group is reserved for system use. You cannot add or delete options in this list."

What can I do to allow edits to the list

WordPress 5.5.8 and CiviCRM 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

The only way to designate an option group as reserved is to do so directly through the database - there is no option to do this through the UI either when it is created via a multiple-choice custom data field or when added directly via Administer > System Settings > Option Groups - there might be a reason that this option group was flagged as reserved, so you might wish to ask whoever is responsible for administering CiviCRM to shed light on the reason and/or ask them to remove the reserved flag altogether so that you can make changes when needed.

Hope this helps,
Tamar